# Retrieving a random unique row from the database table, 6 times, to populate and replace placeholder fields in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a fictional events website which should display various admin created events and I wish to generate unique pages for each of the featured events.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="4u 12u$(mobile)">
      <article class="item">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="../images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <header>
            <h3>Event 1</h3>
         </header>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="../images/pic03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <header>
            <h3>Event 2</h3>
         </header>
      </article>
   </div>
   <div class="4u 12u$(mobile)">
      <article class="item">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="../images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <header>
            <h3>Event 3</h3>
         </header>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="../images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <header>
            <h3>Event 4</h3>
         </header>
      </article>
   </div>
   <div class="4u$ 12u$(mobile)">
      <article class="item">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="../images/pic06.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <header>
            <h3>Event 5</h3>
         </header>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
         <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="../images/pic07.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         <header>
            <h3>Event 6</h3>
         </header>
      </article>
   </div>
</div>
```

Instead of `Event 1, Event 2 ...` I want to have the actual `eventName`'s from my `events` table in the database.

I've used the following code before to generate a table with the fields from the database:

```
<?php
    $queryEvents = "SELECT * FROM events GROUP BY eventStart DESC";
    $resultEvents = $mysqli->query($queryEvents);
?>

<table class="tableList" align="left">
<tr>
</tr>
<?php
while($rowEvents = $resultEvents->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$rowEvents['eventName']}</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"../details.php?eventID={$rowEvents['eventID']}\">View</a></t
    d>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?eventID={$rowEvents['eventID']}\">Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?eventID={$rowEvents['eventID']}\">Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

This however only works with all the values in the database. How can I just retrieve 6 **random** values and each of them be **unique** to replace the `Event 1` (etc) placeholders?

Comment: Use the feared MYSQL `ORDER BY RAND()` to select random rows. [Here](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) is a good write-up on how to implement this.

Comment: You use `GROUP BY eventStart` in query: there are more than one event with same `evenStart`? And if it is, you want retrieve events by random date or random events by each recent date?

Comment: @fusion3k Sorry, I should have posted my database details as part of the question. There are no two events with the same `eventStart`. What I want to do is simply retrieve any random 6 events, regardless of their `eventStart`. I used the `eventStart` as part of another section of my website which displays the most recent events in order from the database. Sorry for the confusion. I was looking just to retrieve the `eventName` to replace the `Event #` placeholders.

Comment: @Olehi so you have to use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6` as suggested above!

Comment: @fusion3k Okay, so the query would be `$queryEvents = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6";`? Will I still have to use the while loop? How do I replace the text? `echo "<h3>{$rowEvents['eventName']}</h3>";`  with the help of the while loop ..or?

Comment: @RyanVincent Interesting idea! Couldn't show us an example of shuffling could you? ;) Table contains literally 20 records

Comment: [shuffle — Shuffle an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php). Just wite the output of your query into a PHP array where the values are the returned rows. Shuffle the array. Then use a `for` loop for the first six entries. The manual entry has examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new query to retrieve randomly events:

```
$queryEvents = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6";
$resultEvents = $mysqli->query($queryEvents);
```

Then, inside HTML, something like this:

```
<?php while( $rowEvents = $resultEvents->fetch_assoc() ): ?>
    <div class="4u 12u$(mobile)">
        <article class="item">
            <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="../images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <header>
                <h3><?php echo $rowEvents['eventName'] ?></h3>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But you have 2 `<article>` in each `<div>`, so you can use a flag, like (i.e.) in this way:

```
<?php
$flag = True;
while( $rowEvents = $resultEvents->fetch_assoc() ): ?>
<?php if( $flag ): ?>
    <div class="4u 12u$(mobile)">
<?php endif; ?>
        <article class="item">
            (...)
        </article>
<?php if( $flag ): ?>
    </div>
<?php
    endif;
    $flag = ! $flag;
?>
```

At the start, `$flag` is set to True, so at the first loop, the `<div>` and `</div>` will printed out; at the end of first loop, `$flag` is set to False, so at next loop the `<div>` will not printed out, at the end of second loop `$flag` is set to True, etc...

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your database query:

```
$queryEvents = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");
$resultEvents = mysqli->fetch_assoc($queryEvents);
```

Your foreach loop to display data:

```
foreach ($resultEvents as $event) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$event['eventName']}</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"../details.php?eventID={$event['eventID']}\">View</a></t
    d>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?eventID={$event['eventID']}\">Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?eventID={$event['eventID']}\">Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```